# Text-styling box - is there a better name for it?

Tags: formatting, textbox, style

I designed this UI element. When you want to add a message in a system, platform, product...And you get these options on how to format your text, insert an image, create a hyperlink, etc. So now I want to add it to my UX team's component library. But I can't think of how is this element called. Does it have a common, well-known name and I just don't know it, cause I'm not a native English speaker? Thank you all for your help!

[image]

Comment: The name I've seen is In-Place Editor. When it supports formatting like in your example, Danielillo's answer is correct, it's a Rich Text Editor.

Answer (score 4):

## Rich-Text Editor

> **Rich-text editor** is the interface for editing rich text within web browsers, which presents the user with a "what-you-see-is-what-you-get" (WYSIWYG) editing area. The aim is to reduce the effort for users trying to express their formatting directly as valid HTML markup.

<sub>*Wikipedia*</sub>

If you google there's a lot of information about **Rich-Text Editors**, I chose the Wikipedia definition that is usually the most concise.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! Yes, that's it, Rich-text Editor or WYSIWYG!

Comment: @izguierdo Thank you! Yes, that's it.